# Switching between multiple views with ImageButtons

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting an error when switching between views. I have `android:onClick="onClick"` on every Image button in the xml. Here is the code

```
    selfHelp = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.selfhelpButton);
    services = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.services);
    messages = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mailButton);
    about = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.aboutButton);
    more = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.moreButton);
    selfHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {               
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SelfHelp.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });
    Services.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {          
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Services.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });

    messages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {               
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Messages.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });

    about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {               
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), About.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });

    more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {               
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), More.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });
```

I have had this working on another page with only one button but the image button doesn't work. Any help will be great

Comment: Please post your error and/or stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two choices

1. remove `android:onClick="onClick"` on each ImageButton because you
   are already set click listener on your button on overriding the
   default **onClick()** method.
2. remove all **setOnclickListener()** methods and in your ImageButtons add attributes:

   ```
   android:onClick="onClick"   
   android:clickable="true"
   ```

in your Activity use:

```
public void onClick(View v){
Intent i = null;
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.services:
       i = new Intent(this,Services.class);
       startActivity(i);
       break;
case R.id.mailButton:
..........
break;

}
```

Comment: @BigT can you post you logcat?

Comment: As i was posting the logcat i found the error. The android manifest had the wrong spelling of the other files. I typed it in manuallly. Thanks for the help